# Is there way a to fetch Wikipedia image metadata in bulk?

Tags: parsing, wikipedia

For example, this image url ([http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:NewYork1777MapRestoredSmall.png](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aNewYork1777MapRestoredSmall.png) ) has information about its Description: "English: Map of the provinces of New York and New Jersey"

I took a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php. It's great for allowing multiple queries at once but it only had fields for:
`timestamp, user, userid, comment, parsedcomment, url, size, dimensions, sha1, mime, thumbmime, metadata, archivename, bitdepth`

No description field. Is the only way to parse this html page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like comment or parsedcomment might give you what you want.  comment seems to return the wiki markup of the Summary section, while parsedcomment seems to return the HTML.